# Jasper fails to find files in /webapps

Tags: jsp, tomcat, taglib

I am trying to get the open source JBilling web application working again with Tomcat 8, after having previously had it working (not sure what's changed) and I found that when I try to open a .jsp page and Jasper tries to compile it, it falls over with a NullPointerException.
I modified Jasper to throw a more sensible exception and found that it was failing to find /WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld even though that file exists at Tomcat's $CATALINA_HOME/webapp/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld

I thought Tomcat was supposed to look in /webapps for files for all applications in addition to the application's own directory ?
What am I doing wrong ?

the .jsp file is very simple:

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld" prefix="tiles" %>

<tiles:insert definition="userLogin" flush="true" />
```

the NullPointerException stack trace was:

16-May-2016 22:43:49.087 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/user] threw exception [Unable to
 compile class for JSP] with root cause

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldCache.getTaglibXml(TldCache.java:101)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:179)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:434)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1448)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:145)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:201)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:333)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:600)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:760)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1480)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have tried Tomcat 8.0.30 and 9.0.0-M4. Both produce identical stack traces.

Comment: What is the JSP file?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that StackOverflow wasn't displaying the JSP. I've edited it so that it displays now thanks.